# how to render a different component after every iteration of map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am fetching data from http://retailsolution.pk/api/allhome I want to display the title of the product and then all the child products below it, I am getting this output: [image] Here's my code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Deals: []
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://retailsolution.pk/api/allhome")
      .then(response => this.setState({ Deals: response.data.Deals }));
  }

  _renderItem(item) {
    return (
      <View style={{ width: 100, height: 130 }}>
        <Image
          style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
          source={{ uri: item.image }}
        />
        <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          {" "}
          {item.name}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderTitle() {
    return this.state.Deals.map(deal => (
      <Text key={deal.parent.id} style={styles.text}>
        {deal.parent.name}
      </Text>
    ));
  }
  renderImage() {
    return this.state.Deals.map(deal => (
      <FlatList
        key={deal.child.product_id}
        style={{ marginTop: 5 }}
        horizontal
        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ width: 5 }} />}
        renderItem={({ item }) => this._renderItem(item)}
        data={[deal.child]}
      />
    ));
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.Deals);
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, marginLeft: 8, marginRight: 8, marginTop: 10 }}>
        {this.renderTitle()}
        {this.renderImage()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In my case `{this.renderTitle()}` gets execute first and maps every value from the api to the app and then `{this.renderImage()}` maps all flatlists to the app.

Is there any way I can run this.renderImage() after every iteration of rhis.renderTitle()?

Comment: Can you please paste the response here

Comment: @RohanVeer I have given link of the API, there's no issue in retrieving the data, I just don't know how to display the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do it using nested loop.
Try something like this -

```
{this.state.Deals.map(deal => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Text key={deal.parent.id} style={styles.text}>
        {deal.parent.name}
      </Text>
      {deal.child.map(item => {
        return (
          <FlatList
            key={item.product_id}
            style={{ marginTop: 5 }}
            horizontal
            ItemSeparatorComponent={() => <View style={{ width: 5 }} />}
            renderItem={({ item }) => this._renderItem(item)}
            data={[item]}
          />
        );
      })}}
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Comment: my bad, it's data={item} not {[item]}, it's working now but now I am getting all the child under each title

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is to call a function after the fetch that will create the section data for the Flatlist with the correct format:

```
sections = [{title: 'Latest', data:["The products data array"]}, {title: 'second section', data : ["Other products"]}, and so on...]`
```